# SVG blur filter inline in CSS. How to?

Tags: css, svg, filter, inline

I would like to blur **texts** and **images** when they are seen through a given semi-transparent `div`. This means that I wouldn't like everything in the background to become blurry.

I have found a very interesting example done by a member of StackOverflow:

```css
body {
  filter: url(#frost-me);
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <rect id="frosty-area" fill="red" x="100" y="100" width="400" height="300"/>
    <filter id="frost-me" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
      <feImage xlink:href="#frosty-area"/>
      <feComposite operator="in" in="SourceGraphic" result="selection"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10"/>\
      <feComponentTransfer>
        <feFuncA type="discrete" tableValues="1 1"/>
      </feComponentTransfer>
    <feComposite operator="in" in2="selection"/>
      <feComposite operator="over" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <a href="https://codepen.io/mullany/pen/mwrejb">Source</a>
    hqksdhkqhsd ksqdh lkqjsh Fames suscipit potenti ut rhoncus curabitur
    tellus leo libero pulvinar fermentum fringilla nisl scelerisque lacus
    viverra gravida penatibus integer vehicula aenean adipiscing lacinia
    hendrerit curae duis ligula felis placerat
    nullam elementum morbi urna facilisis vulputate magna congue amet id
    neque montes varius accumsan aliquet vivamus ultricies lectus mattis
    volutpat sociis Commodo id est cras venenatis rutrum ante diam lorem
    blandit duis morbi felis sit mattis ut litora
    sollicitudin habitasse semper suscipit lacinia nisl convallis urna
    risus metus sem posuere accumsan suspendisse eros enim curae dis
    libero primis aliquet nullam parturient praesent sagittis taciti nam
    in maecenas nascetur platea tincidunt magnis
  </div>
</div>
```

Actually, this fiddle is my minimalist version of Mikael Mullany's nice work.

Since I will probably **not be able (allowed) to customize the html or the php** (the page is rendered by Wordpress) I thought that I could define and call the svg directly by and into the CSS style sheet. I have tried to do this but didn't succeeded.

Please see here:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width='0' height='0'><defs><rect id='frosty-area' fill='red' x='100' y='100' width='400' height='300'/><filter id='frost-me' x='0%' y='0%' width='100%' height='100%'><feImage xlink:href='#frosty-area'/><feComposite operator='in' in='SourceGraphic' result='selection'/> <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation='10'/><feComponentTransfer><feFuncA type='discrete' tableValues='11'/></feComponentTransfer><feComposite operator='in' in2='selection'/><feComposite operator='over' in2='SourceGraphic'/></filter></defs></svg>");
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <a href="https://codepen.io/mullany/pen/mwrejb">Source</a>
    hqksdhkqhsd ksqdh lkqjsh Fames suscipit potenti ut rhoncus curabitur
    tellus leo libero pulvinar fermentum fringilla nisl scelerisque lacus
    viverra gravida penatibus integer vehicula aenean adipiscing lacinia
    hendrerit curae duis ligula felis placerat
    nullam elementum morbi urna facilisis vulputate magna congue amet id
    neque montes varius accumsan aliquet vivamus ultricies lectus mattis
    volutpat sociis Commodo id est cras venenatis rutrum ante diam lorem
    blandit duis morbi felis sit mattis ut litora
    sollicitudin habitasse semper suscipit lacinia nisl convallis urna
    risus metus sem posuere accumsan suspendisse eros enim curae dis
    libero primis aliquet nullam parturient praesent sagittis taciti nam
    in maecenas nascetur platea tincidunt magnis
  </div>
</div>
```

There is more, it's told elsewhere on StackOverFlow that to better succeed in doing this, it is a good practice to base64 encode the svg. That is what I did, but without success either:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8, PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIwIj48ZGVmcz48cmVjdCBpZ D0iZnJvc3R5LWFyZWEiICBmaWxsPSJyZWQiIHg9IjEwMCIgeT0iMT AwIiB3aWR0aD0iNDAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjMwMCIvPjxmaWx0ZXIgaWQ 9ImZyb3N0LW1lIiB4PSIwJSIgeT0iMCUiIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBo ZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiPjxmZUltYWdlIHhsaW5rOmhyZWY9IiNmcm9zd HktYXJlYSIvPjxmZUNvbXBvc2l0ZSBvcGVyYXRvcj0iaW4iIGluPS JTb3VyY2VHcmFwaGljIiByZXN1bHQ9InNlbGVjdGlvbiIvPiA8ZmV HYXVzc2lhbkJsdXIgc3RkRGV2aWF0aW9uPSIxMCIvPjxmZUNvbXBv bmVudFRyYW5zZmVyPjxmZUZ1bmNBIHR5cGU9ImRpc2NyZXRlIiB0Y WJsZVZhbHVlcz0iMSAxIi8+ PC9mZUNvbXBvbmVudFRyYW5zZmVyPjxmZUNvbXBvc2l0ZSBvcGVyY XRvcj0iaW4iIGluMj0ic2VsZWN0aW9uIi8+ PGZlQ29tcG9zaXRlIG9wZXJhdG9yPSJvdmVyIiBpbjI9IlNvdXJjZ UdyYXBoaWMiLz48L2ZpbHRlcj48L2RlZnM+PC9zdmc+");
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <a href="https://codepen.io/mullany/pen/mwrejb">Source</a>
    hqksdhkqhsd ksqdh lkqjsh Fames suscipit potenti ut rhoncus curabitur
    tellus leo libero pulvinar fermentum fringilla nisl scelerisque lacus
    viverra gravida penatibus integer vehicula aenean adipiscing lacinia
    hendrerit curae duis ligula felis placerat
    nullam elementum morbi urna facilisis vulputate magna congue amet id
    neque montes varius accumsan aliquet vivamus ultricies lectus mattis
    volutpat sociis Commodo id est cras venenatis rutrum ante diam lorem
    blandit duis morbi felis sit mattis ut litora
    sollicitudin habitasse semper suscipit lacinia nisl convallis urna
    risus metus sem posuere accumsan suspendisse eros enim curae dis
    libero primis aliquet nullam parturient praesent sagittis tacitinam
    in maecenas nascetur platea tincidunt magnis
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What you are trying there won't work. You are setting the background to an SVG file. That SVG can be displayed as an image, but nothing in it (such as your filter) is accessible.

Comment: Thank you very much for paying attention for my request. I am not sure to understand what you write. Not because it is unclear but because I don't understand exactly how the source code works. But to clarify our dialog I think starting form the initial model is probably safer. There you can see the complet code that inspired me : https://codepen.io/mullany/pen/mwrejb

Comment: If we clear all the unnecessary stuff in these codes, we get the first snippet that I have created here above. It still works fine for my goal.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. The filter definition has to be in your HTML. It can't be in a `background-image`. It is not accessible there.

Comment: Ah, OK. I notice that if I don't "call" the SVG by the CSS, it is not visible although it is inline in the html. I could take this "opportunity" to actually add the SVG code in the theme header (WordPress) for example or in a module and "call" the SVG ID in my custom CSS.